# Unable to replace a string using a regular expression

Tags: javascript, jquery, replace

I was playing with jsfiddle here: http://jsfiddle.net/dm9eebz9/

HTML

```
<div id="wrapper">
    <p class="body">Line 1
        <br>
        <br>Line 3</p>
    <p class="body">Line 1
        <br>Line 2
        <br>
        <br>
        <br>
        <br>Line 6</p>
    <p class="body">Line 1
        <br>Line 2</p>
</div>
```

Javascript/jQuery

```
$('#wrapper p.body').each(function () {
    var temp = $(this).innerHTML;
    this.innerHTML = temp.replace(/(<br>)+/gim, "<br>");
});
```

My goal was to try to get rid of more than 2 `<br>`'s when they occur.  However, it doesn't seem to recognize temp.  Is this jsfiddle behavior, or am I making an obvious error?

Comment: I don't think there's an `innerHTML` property on a jQuery array.

Comment: Read these articles to [learn](http://juliepagano.com/blog/2014/05/18/javascript-debugging-for-beginners) [how to](http://www.creativebloq.com/javascript/javascript-debugging-beginners-3122820) [**debug** JavaScript](https://developers.google.com/chrome-developer-tools/docs/javascript-debugging), so you can and help yourself.

Comment: What exactly is the final result? Do you want to remove the `br` if there are more than 2 *consecutive* `br` nodes? I.e. it would remove the last two `br` in the second paragraph?

Comment: if you want to access javascript functions off of jQuery, you need to do this `$(this)[0]` and it gives you back that raw javascript.

Comment: @No1_Melman: Don't confuse JavaScript with DOM. `$(this)[0]` returns a *DOM element* which lets you access the *DOM API*. Of course you are using JavaSCript, but jQuery is JavaScript as well.

Comment: @FelixKling yeah thats what I meant

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The jsfiddled: http://jsfiddle.net/pe6w7z1e/1/

The idea is: there will be one break and one/more (one/more spacenewline + break) >> replace with just one break

Here is the modified code:

```
$('p.body').each(function () {
    var elem = $(this)
    var temp = elem.html();
    elem.html(temp.replace(/<br>(\s+<br>)+/img, "<br>"));

});
```

*Please mark as answer if it answers your question*

I think it is better to use jquery all cases. Mixing of Jquery and raw javascript is not good concept.

Comment: .replace is a javascript method, not jquery

Comment: Thanks Ivo for your comments. Could you show any reference? What's the alternative for jquery?

Comment: *"What's the alternative for jquery? "* There is none because jQuery is not a library for text processing.

Comment: Ah then we can only use replace here..
Thanks Felix

Comment: I'd use either jquery or javascript only, but the system I am working in (spiceworks) seems to have some major issues with certain things.

Answer (score 1):

Use `.html()` not `innerHTML`;

The regex pattern `/(<br>\s*)+/` takes white space into account with `\s*` which matches 0 or more white space characters.

```
$('p.body').each(function () {
    var temp = $(this).html();
    $(this).html(temp.replace(/(<br>\s*)+/gim, "<br>"));
});
```

Also as commented, [use your browsers console](https://developer.chrome.com/devtools/docs/javascript-debugging) for debugging and always [RTFM](http://api.jquery.com/html/).

Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/dm9eebz9/4/

Answer (score 1):

I really don't think regular expressions are the right tool for this. You can use a combination of [`.contents`](http://api.jquery.com/contents) and [`.filter`](http://api.jquery.com/filter) to remove the duplicate `<br />` tags:

```
var prev = null;
var $nodes = $('.body')
    .contents()
    .filter(function () {
        return this.nodeType !== 3 || $.trim(this.data) !== "";
    });

for (var i = 1; i < $nodes.length; i++) {
    if ($nodes.eq(i).is('br') && $nodes.eq(i-1).is('br')) {
        $nodes.eq(i).remove();
    }
}
```

The complexity here is the text nodes in between the `<br />` tags, thus the two-step process.

**Example:** http://jsfiddle.net/dm9eebz9/9/

Answer (score 0):

You need to use the correct object for the `innerHTML` property. That is a DOM object property and not a jQuery one. You can either use the `innerHTML` DOM property on the DOM element:

```
$('p.body').each(function () {
    var temp = this.innerHTML;
    this.innerHTML = temp.replace(/(<br>)+/gim, "<br>");
});
```

JSFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/dm9eebz9/6/

or use the html() method on a jQuery object:

```
$('p.body').each(function () {
    var temp = $(this).html();
    this.html(temp.replace(/(<br>)+/gim, "<br>"));
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/dm9eebz9/7/

Note a "correct" line break is `<br/>`, not `<br>` but I gather you cannot change that

Comment: <br/> cannot be used, as the pages I am editing have <br>, correct or not.

Comment: Was updating the JSFiddle, but I am dumping this answer as the other answer is far simpler :)